# How to get a nullable DateTime serialized on WCF service

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, wcf

I have a WCF service with a *nullable* datetime member in *DataContract* as showed below. Because of business rules this *datamember* can't have the **EmitDefaultValue** setted to **true** and the type must be a "*DateTime?*"
.

```
[DataContract(Name = "DADOS")]
public class Dados 
{
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Name = "NASCIMENTO")]
    public DateTime? DtNascimento = null;
}
```

My service contract is specified like below, see that I have to have two versions of Webinvoke method to keep different systems interoperability (Json and XML responses):

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IRestService
{
    [OperationContract(Name = "ConsultaDadosXml")]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "ConsultaDados/xml?token={token}")]
    Dados ConsultaDadosXml(string token);

    [OperationContract(Name = "ConsultaDadosJson")]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "ConsultaDados/json?token={token}")]
    Dados ConsultaDadosJson(string token);
}
```

The problem is, when the *DtNascimento* value comes with a good value from the database, everything works fine. When this value is really **null** on the database, the XML/JSON response comes without the NASCIMENTO tag, is this happening  because we have **EmitDefaultValue** = **false**. I can set my database to send me a empty value when this occurs, but my serialized object comes with a MinDate value on the responses.

Xml version:

```
<DADOS>
    <NASCIMENTO>1900-01-01T00:00:00</NASCIMENTO>
</DADOS>
```

Json version:

```
{
    "NASCIMENTO": "/Date(-2208981600000-0200)/",
}
```

What I really need is an empty variable shown on the answers when this value is null because there are other systems plugged on the web service trying to interpret those values, so the best solution would be keep empty variables:

Xml version:

```
<DADOS>
    <NASCIMENTO></NASCIMENTO>
</DADOS>
```

Json version:

```
{
    "NASCIMENTO": "",
}
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Tks

Léo

Comment: Could you explain this statement " Because of business rules this datamember can't have the EmitDefaultValue setted to true"? I ask because you do expect the attribute to be sent in the response based on your post. Are you using DataContract class for something else internally in your application?

Comment: Would `<NASCIMENTO></NASCIMENTO>` be OK?  It means exactly the same thing as `<NASCIMENTO />`

Comment: @RajaraamMurali  is to long to explain but, imagine that the users can decide with some database configuration, if the tag will or not appear on the response. Yes, I'm using the DataContract in all the service.

Comment: @dbc - Yes, is the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a proxy string-valued private property that returns an empty string for a `null` `DateTime?` value, and serialize that.  It produces an empty element in the following format:

> ```
> <NASCIMENTO></NASCIMENTO>
> ```

which is defined by the [XML standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags) to have the same meaning as `<NASCIMENTO />`.

```
[DataContract(Name = "DADOS")]
public class Dados
{
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public DateTime? DtNascimento { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Name = "NASCIMENTO")]
    string DtNascimentoString
    {
        get
        {
            if (DtNascimento == null)
                return string.Empty;
            return XmlConvert.ToString(DtNascimento.Value, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.RoundtripKind);
        }
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                DtNascimento = null;
            else
                DtNascimento = XmlConvert.ToDateTime(value, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.RoundtripKind);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your solution of proxy string-valued, it works fine and I will try to use but now a facing another problem ... I'll edit my answare.